# Android SharedPreferences clear values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

if `sp.clear();` and `sp.commit();` is executed to clear the values of SharedPreferences.

It will only clear the values  for the particular instance that was used to initialize the SharedPreferences?

It will not clear whatever values that was stored on SharedPreferences by other application?

Comment: How did you get shared pref?

Comment: hello bro, i did something like this below:                                   
        getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).sp().putInt(strvalue,                   intvalue).commit();                                                    

just like that, retrieving and and storing seems to be fine.

But i'm not sure if i use the clear and commit whether it might clear other sharedpref value on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sp.remove().The remove() method will remove the shared preference.

Comment: Thanks kgandroid, Great Idea! :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `sp.clear();` will remove only one shared preferences file's values.

When you use a method to get access to shared preferences, you specify the file name using `getSharedPreferences (String name, int mode)` method. All the preferences in this file only will be removed.

If you use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` to get access to your shared preferences, it will still remove values from only one file which is the default file for the context you specified in the parameter.